# Google Apps with own SMTP server and local emails

Tags: smtp, google-apps, postfix-mta

Currently we're using Google's SMTP to send emails from our webserver to the registered users. Because of the restrictions (500 mails per day) that's no longer feasible. Therefore we set up a postfix on our machine and reconfigured the webapps to use this one. Now, postfix delivers emails going to our own emails addresses (*@gibbonsfive.de) locally and not to Google Apps anymore. On top, it won't deliver any email to the mailing lists configured on the Google server because it says the user / alias does not exist. Is there any way to make it work the following way:

- Google Apps for all our email adresses, including Google's SMTP server (working)
- Webapps are using our own SMTP (working) and emails send to a user with our own domain (*@gibbonsfive.de) are not delivered locally (does not work)

Our setup:

bind-config for the domain:

```
...
ns                      IN      A       78.46.106.246
ns1.rollernet.us.       IN      A       208.79.240.3
ns2.rollernet.us.       IN      A       208.79.241.3

@                       IN      MX    10    aspmx.l.google.com.
@                       IN      MX    10    alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
@                       IN      MX    10    alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
@                       IN      MX    10     aspmx2.googlemail.com.
@                       IN      A       78.46.106.246 
mail                    IN      A       78.46.106.246
...
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

message_size_limit = 209715200
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

smtp_use_tls=yes
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_sasl_path=smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated
        permit_mynetworks
smtpd_recipient_restrictions= 
        permit_mynetworks, 
        permit_sasl_authenticated, 
        reject_unauth_destinatio

smtpd_helo_required=yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions=reject_invalid_helo_hostname
myhostname = romeo.gibbonsfive.de 
myorigin = gibbonsfive.de

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, localhost.$myorigin, $myorigin
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there any way to make it work the following way: 1. Google Apps for all our email adresses, including Google's SMTP server (working), 2. Webapps are using our own SMTP (working) and emails send to a user with our own domain (*@gibbonsfive.de) are not delivered locally (does not work)

Comment: Sorry, I clearly missed that part. I am a Google Apps expert and know very little about Postfix -- this problem is Postfix not configured correctly. What you are trying to do is possible with Google Apps. Sorry, I could not be of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the 'mydestination' configuration fixed it!

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```